# If $R$ is an infinite ring, then $R$ has either infinitely many zero divisors, or no zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Please help me to prove that if $R$ is an infinite ring, then $R$ has either an infinite number of zero divisors, or it has no zero divisors.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: Is commutativity assumed? It would be good to add that tag, if so. I'm not sure how Zhen Lin's solution works in the noncommutative case.

Comment: I don't know ring is commutative or not. There's no information about it in this problem.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ or any other domain has one zero divisor..

Answer (score 12):

**Hint.** Let $a$ be a zero-divisor. Consider $\{  a b : b \in R \} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. This is a non-empty set of zero-divisors in $R$. If it is infinite, then you are done. Otherwise it is finite; what are the implications of this? (Use the pigeonhole principle.)

Comment: so, If I understood it correctly: by pigeonhole principle, there exists an infinite subset X of R and an element x from X such that ax=ay for all y from X. so

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Therefore we have infinite set y -x and I do not know, what to do with it?

Comment: oh, thank you,  I get it

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof by contradiction:

Assume that there are only finitely many zero divisors in $R$ and let them be $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and denote the set of these $A$. Fix some element $b \in R, b \ne a_i$ for all $i$. Convince yourself that there are infinitely many elements $c \in R, c \ne a_i$ for all $i$ such that $b-c \ne a_i$ for all $i$, and let $C$ be the set of these. Given $x \in R$ that is not a zero divisor we must have that $a_i \mapsto x a_i$ is a bijection of $A$ otherwise $x$ would be a zero divisor. But then since there are only finitely many bijections of $A$ since $A$ is finite, and there are infinitely many elements in $C$, we see that we can find an elements $y$ in $C$ that gives the same bijection of $A$ as $b$ , but then $(b-y)a_i = b a_i - y a_i = 0$ hence $b-y$ is a zero divisor, a contradiction.