# Let $R$ be an infinite commmutative ring which contains a zero divisor. Show that there exists infinite many zero divisors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm making exercises to prepare for my ring theory exam.

> Let $R$ be an infinite commmutative ring which contains a zero
>   divisor. Show that there exists infinite many zero divisors.

Let $a\in R$ a zero divisor. Then $a⋅b=0$ for some element $b≠0$ in $R$. If $a$ or $b$ has infinite order, then I can find infinite zero divisors.  But otherwise, I don't see why this should be true. I think I need to do something with the fact that $R$ is commutative. A hint or a detailed solution are both appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked many times here, for example [If $R$ is an infinite ring, then $R$ has either infinitely many zero divisors, or no zero divisors](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315735/if-r-is-an-infinite-ring-then-r-has-either-infinitely-many-zero-divisors-o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a$ be a zero divisor. Consider two cases:

- $Ra$ is an infinite set.
- $Ra$ is a finite set.

(If $R\to Ra$ has finite range, $xa=ra$ has infinitely many solutions $x$ for some $r\in R$, so...)

Comment: Suppose $Ra$ is an infinite set. Then all elements in $Ra-\{0\}$ are zero divisors. So there are infinite zero divisors. Thinking about the other case.

Comment: $xa=ra$ has to have infinite many solutions for some $r\in R$, otherwise there would be finite many elements in $R$. We know that $xab=rab=0$. therefore there are infinite zero divisors of the form $xa$ ? No this isn't true because all $xa$ are equal. I don't see what to do.

Comment: Or can I choose $r$ as the element $r≠0$ with $ra=0$ ?

Comment: @Kasper Consider rewriting $xr=ar$ as $(x-a)r=0$.

Comment: Aah, I see it now. $xa=ra$ has infinitely many solutions $x$ for some $r\in R$. Therefore I can choose $r≠0$. And $(x-a)r=0$ for infinitely many $x$. So $(x-a)$ is infinitely many times not zero. So we have infinite zero divisors.

Comment: But where do I use the fact that $R$ is commutative ?

Comment: @Kasper This proof works even if $R$ is not commutative (but then you would need to specify that $a$ is a left zero divisor).

Answer (score 0):

If $ab=0$ for $b\neq 0$ then it implies that $a^nb=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Thus if $a$ is not nilpotent all $a^n$ are zero divisors.

Comment: If $a$ is nilpotent it only has *finitely* many distinct powers.

Comment: @ anon: yes, you are right. My answer is true for only non-nilpotent $a$.